# error: parse error on input ‘where’ | 4 | where f y x = [x]:y | ^^^^^

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
drop 95 (foldl f [] [1..100])


where f y x = [x]:y
```

main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

Comment: Syntax is the first hurdle when learning a language. To get a feel for it, I would start with much simpler examples than what you're trying now, and then work towards the more difficult stuff

Answer (score 6):

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
```

Correct, this is a type signature for a procedure named `main`.

```
drop 95 (foldl f [] [1..100])
```

This line is nonsense.  Expressions are not valid at the top level.  Suppose I told a C compiler `1 + 7`.  What should it make of that?  It seems unreasonable.

Perhaps, having given main a type, you intended to define main: `main = ...`.  Even then, the `drop` function is not an IO action.  You probably want to perform the computation then *use* the result somehow like printing it to the screen.

```
where f y x = [x]:y
```

Again this is nonsensical without the definition of a procedure, such as I proposed with `main = ...`.  Imagine I said "at the movies" and left off the "meet us at seven" - the context is rather critical.

Putting it together, I suspect you are looking for:

```
main :: IO () -- a type signature much like a C prototype
main = print (drop 95 (foldl f [] [1..100]))
  where f y x = [x]:y
```

Be aware that the indentation of `where` is important.